# Hadoop Streaming- Set max number of maps per node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Is it possible to set number of map task running per node.
I'm using Hadoop Streaming for crawling data, and I need only one map task per node to avoid blocks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irrespective of Streaming or not, the maximum # of mappers per node can be set using the `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` parameters. The parameter has to be set in the `mapred-site.xml` file on the node, this property has no effect when set on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried playing with the following settings in your job.xml?

```
mapred.max.maps.per.node=1
mapred.max.reduces.per.node=1
```

These are default to -1, unlimited (except of course, by available slots).